# SSL socket Connection Pooling in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, ssl, connection-pooling

I am creating a SSL server-client. Till now, what I have implemented is a simple server which can talk to a single client (no threading, that is). Now, I want to scale this application for multiple clients and I want to use connection pooling for that. Now, do I need to use threading for that or is there inbuilt library that I can use. Any examples, link etc would work.

PS: I have tried googling but have not found a suitable link.

Below is my code if required:

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

public class SSLServer {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        String ksname = "file.jks";
        char kspass[] = "pass".toCharArray();
        char ctpass[] = "pass".toCharArray();

        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksname), kspass);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, ctpass);
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(4321);
            //printServerSocketInfo(s);
            SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
            //printSocketInfo(c);

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));

            w.write("Server starts\n");

            w.flush();
            String k = null;
            while((k = r.readLine()) != null){
                //do something
                if(k.equals("end"))
                    break;
                w.write(resolve(k));
                w.newLine();
                w.flush();
            }
            w.close();
            r.close();
            c.close();
            s.close();

        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
          System.out.println("Socket class: "+s.getClass());
          System.out.println("   Remote address = "
             +s.getInetAddress().toString());
          System.out.println("   Remote port = "+s.getPort());
          System.out.println("   Local socket address = "
             +s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
          System.out.println("   Local address = "
             +s.getLocalAddress().toString());
          System.out.println("   Local port = "+s.getLocalPort());
          System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
             +s.getNeedClientAuth());
          SSLSession ss = s.getSession();
          System.out.println("   Cipher suite = "+ss.getCipherSuite());
          System.out.println("   Protocol = "+ss.getProtocol());
    }

    private static void printServerSocketInfo(SSLServerSocket s) {
          System.out.println("Server socket class: "+s.getClass());
          System.out.println("   Socket address = "
             +s.getInetAddress().toString());
          System.out.println("   Socket port = "
             +s.getLocalPort());
          System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
             +s.getNeedClientAuth());
          System.out.println("   Want client authentication = "
             +s.getWantClientAuth());
          System.out.println("   Use client mode = "
             +s.getUseClientMode());
    }

    private static String resolve(String p){
        //some implementation
        return "something";
    }

    }
```

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class SSLClient {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();

        try {
            SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("localhost", 4321);
            printSocketInfo(c);
            c.startHandshake();
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));

            //to input hex code message
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String k = null;
            while((k = r.readLine()) != null){
                //send message to server
                System.out.println(k);
                System.out.flush();
                k = in.readLine();
                if(k.equals("."))
                    break;
                System.out.println(k);
                System.out.flush();
                w.write(k);
                w.newLine();
                w.flush();
            }
            w.close();
            r.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no connection pooling of any kind here. The code you've posted creates one connection and then exits. It doesn't have any need for connection pooling. It's entirely unclear what you're asking here, or whether you know what connection pooling really is, or why you think you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is able to connect to multiple clients. In your code you've initialized a `SSLServerSocket` who's task it is to wait for additional clients - each of them will get it's own `SSLSocket`.

If your server isn't able to handle all clients, you'd use something like a **loadbalancer** which spreads the incoming requests to different server.

**Connection Pooling** is typically used inside a server - e.g. for talking to a database.

Does this answer your question? If not, is your intention to spread the requests to more than one server or to get to know what connection pooling is for?

Comment: Ok. My ultimate goal for this is to implement an application which is going to serve a lot of requests. I'm only getting started with this, so if you could answer a few doubts.

Comment: If you'd use an application server like tomcat for your application then the server would do the *thread-stuff*. If you want to implement your own small server than I would indeed create a thread for each socket - that means for each client. Of course it depends on what you do with your server but with actual standard hardware you can serve >>**a lot**<< of clients!! ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It helped. So, do you mean I won't need to implement threading on my part?

Comment: It depends! Do you want to use/build a javaee server or an application server or do you want to build your own socket-handling-server on your own? If the last thing then you've to work with Threads!

Comment: Ok. One last thing I suppose. Here is the situation- internal processing for a client request needs some processing with another server, with which I need to make a secure connection (this other server is not a db). Now, can I use connection pooling in this scenario. If yes, how can it be implemented (links/ref) and if not, what (similar)can be used?

Comment: No, this scenario is the same as the connection between the client and the server. The client sends the request to the server and the server does the ServerSockt-handling. In your scenario the server with the "internal processing for a client" is the client and the another server is the server. Connection Pooling is used within one server not for the communication between servers.

Comment: Ok. So, any alternate for this?

Comment: I've no idea about the size / performance / load of your system. Normally I would assume that you don't need any alternate. If so, than you need more of *another server* and a *load balancer* in between of them.

Comment: Connection pooling is also used by clients, e.g. Web browers. When used in a server as you describe, the server is acting as a client to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Connection pooling is implenented at the client.

At the server end, all you can do is accept connections and not terminate them until closed by the client, or until some read timeout occurs trying to read the second or subsequent request.

Comment: What I have read and understood, connection pooling, in simple words is keeping some already created (probably persistent) connections ahead of time and give it to the client who requests it. So, why would it be implemented on client (and not server)

Comment: And even if it is right, can you please refer me to some documentation/ link etc. so that I can understand and implement it for my application

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A server can't give a connection to a client. Only a client can do that, from its own connection pool. I've already given you quite enough information for a server-side implementation.

Comment: Ok. I get it, ie. why pool be implemented on the client. Can you also refer as to how can I improve my current implementation to connection pooling.

Comment: Why? The code you've posted creates one connection and then exits. It doesn't have any need for connection pooling. It's entirely unclear what you're asking here, or whether you know what connection pooling really is, or why you think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

With Respect to Connection Pooling , As per your statement, i guess, you want to do in Client Side
**Server Side** : THis can be implemented by using MultiThreading

- A Long Running Thread,which waits on accept() method on Socket/Socketchannel

Below is a code Snippet
Server side

```
     ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
        while(!isStopped()){
                try {
    ServerSocketChannel socChnl1 = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            socChnl1.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
                    SocketChannel obj=socChnl1 .accept();
                    
                    threadPool.execute(new WorkerThread(obj);
                    
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

For Client Side

- Option 1 - to use Apache commons Client Pool
- [sample code](https://github.com/AdamGamboa/socket-pool)